# nodejs - TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to redirect from server and show a web page depending on the switch result, but I am getting the next error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.
cga

My server.js Code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

switch(request.url){

    case '/':
        template = "home.html";
        break;
    case '/nodejs':
        template = "node.html";
        break;
    default:
        template = "404.html";
        break;

}

fs.readfile('./templates/' + template , function(err, data) {

    response.write(data);
    response.end();
});

}).listen(3000, 'localhost');
```

Comment: It's just a typo, and you should add an encoding to make sure `data` isn't a buffer, but a string.

Comment: Thank you very much, Adeneo. I shall taking account your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fs.readfile` should be `fs.readFile`.

Comment: Oh My God! Thank you very much for your help, major-mann. As you've checked, I am new to this business ;-)

Comment: It probably wouldn't have helped specifically with this error, but you should use a tool like jshint to check your code for things like typos :)

Comment: I just started to use Sublime Text 2. And it seems that "understands" Javascript, but not nodejs. Do you think jshint is more suitable to work with node? Thanks again.

Comment: jshint is a tool, not a text editor. You won't find much static protection with javascript. You can get a jshint plugin for sublime (Which you can trigger manually to check your code)

Comment: I just checked that there is a jshint version for sublime text v2 and v3. Thank you for your advice.